# How to write a code into a .txt file with Python?

Tags: python, string, formatting

I have got a Python code, what i want to write into a .txt file, but I always get format error (because of the structure). How can I do this output in the correct form?I used # to see where start and end my "string" part.

Here what I tried:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#!/bin/sh
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import urllib2
import subprocess
import unicodecsv as csv
import os
import sys
import io

array = ['link1', 'link2', 'link3']

string = #MY STRING IS START HERE
("browser = webdriver.Firefox()
datatable=[]
   browser.get('%s')  WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(lambda s: s.execute_script("return jQuery.active==0"))
time.sleep(5)
html = browser.page_source
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
 \n")
#AND MY STRING END HERE

file="/Users/Adam/Desktop/data.txt"

with open(file, "w") as f:
    for i in array:
        f.write(string % i)

f.close()
```

EDIT:

```
string2= """query = """ load data local infile '/usr/src/Python-2.7.13/output.csv' 
into table ARRIVALS
fields terminated by ';'
enclosed by '"'
lines terminated by '\n'
ignore 1 lines;
""" """
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to write string over several lines, You must use triple-quotes, instead of single ones.

My guess is that your code will break here:

```
string = #MY STRING IS START HERE
("browser = webdriver.Firefox()
datatable=[]
   browser.get('%s')  WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(lambda s: s.execute_script("return jQuery.active==0"))
time.sleep(5)
html = browser.page_source
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
 \n")
```

because it can't read string this way.

Using

```
string = """browser = webdriver.Firefox()
datatable=[]
browser.get('%s')  WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(lambda s: s.execute_script("return jQuery.active==0"))
time.sleep(5)
html = browser.page_source
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
\n""")
```

should fix the issue.

For edited question: You should replace double-quotes in the string with escape code.

So, instead of

```
string = """ some text """ here """ """
```

You should use

```
string = """ some text \"\"\" here \"\"\" """
```

Comment: Ah it is working, but what can I do, if I have got a MYSQL part in my code with is start like this """ -> this is break it! I edited my question, and you can see it.

Comment: Awesome, thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

As multiline comment can be achieved by """ you can use :

```
    string = """("browser = webdriver.Firefox()
datatable=[]
browser.get('%s')  WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(lambda s: s.execute_script("return jQuery.active==0"))
time.sleep(5)
html = browser.page_source
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
 \n")"""
```

Using single quotes:

```
string = '''"""query = """ load data local infile '/usr/src/Python-2.7.13/output.csv' 
into table ARRIVALS
fields terminated by ';'
enclosed by '"'
lines terminated by '\n'
ignore 1 lines;
"""'''
```

Comment: But what can I do, if I have got a MYSQL part in my code with is start like this """ -> this is break it! I edited my question, and you can see it.

Comment: You can also use single quotes for a multiline comment like shown below :